# Woocommerce and Revolut Gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Revolut Business account and I have my Wordpress website with WooCommerce and Revolut Gateway for WooCommerce. I generate on my Revolut Business a Merchant API and I pasted into Revolut Gateway API Settings BUT when I try to pay via Revolut Gateway - Credit Cards I got the payment declined ; same thing if I try to pay with Revolut Gateway - Revolut Pay (because I have also my personal Revolut card) I got  the operation refused.... Since I put correctly the Merchant API , do you know what I could do to solve that issue?
Thanks a lot to all!!!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

- Reset the gateway details stored in Woo commerce
- Watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxZE0xXYcDo) on how to configure Revolut Gateway for Woo Commerce
- Even if you still face issues, I might suggest you a cache plugin named as Lightspeed cache plugin. Install it and clear your cache
- Reset woo commerce settings
- Contact the gateway customer care, they might help you

Comment: HI @bhavya-lodaya , first thank you for your answer... but I'd like to ask you how I can just reset the gateway details stored in woocommerce?.... looking in the DB I found a table called wc_revolut_orders where there are so many records but I didn't made so much orders because Revolut Gateway doesn't work so I just did like 3-5 orders try...maybe is that table I should empty for that?.... Plus about configure Revolut Gateway I followed this official Revolut's page at https://developer.revolut.com/docs/accept-payments/plugins/woocommerce/configuration/

Comment: You can try this to clear cache https://woocommerce.com/document/payments/faq/clear-account-cache/                          OR another thing you can do is reset whole woo commerce https://woostify.com/how-to-reset-woocommerce/   and the reconfigure This might solve your problems.